# Updating multiple rows with a value calculated from another column

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with a row that looks like this:

(**20091231**48498429, '...', '...')

The first part, id, is a timestamp followed by a random number. (needed to work with other parts in the system) The data already exists in the table.

I want to create a column, timestamp, and extract just the date (20091231) and update all the rows with the timestamp.

1. How can I do this for all the rows with SQL? (i.e. update them all with some sort of a function?)
2. What kind of default value should I assign the column to make sure that future inserts correctly extract the date?

**UPDATE** - Please read the comments by bobince in the first answered question by Jonathan Sampson on how we got to the answer. This is the final query that worked:

```
UPDATE table SET rdate=substring(convert(rid,char(20)),1,8);
```

The problem was that I was using `substring` as `substring( str, 0, 8 )` whereas it should be `substring( str, 1, 8 )`. I guess we're all used to 0 as the beginning position! More info here on [substring](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)

Related to: [multiple updates in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(colDate,0,8) as 'date' 
FROM someTable
```

Or am I mistaken?

```
UPDATE someTable
SET newDateField = SUBSTRING(colDate,0,8)
```

Would likely work too. Untested.

Comment: ...I also want to be able to insert it right back into the table. In all the rows.

Comment: The UPDATE option I added might help there.

Comment: This is not working. I keep getting "query returned no resultset". Could it be because the 'colDate' (i.e. 2009123148498429) is stored as a BIGINT and not a string?

Comment: +1. I don't understand why people are jumping straight for the sub-selects in what would appear to be, unless I've missed something, an absolutely straightforward UPDATE task.

Comment: Try colDate/100000000 instead.

Comment: @Ben: the length of the random number varies...so that doesn't work.

Comment: Ah OK, if you need int to string use CONVERT. You get a free truncate whilst you're at it: “SET newDateField = CONVERT(colDate, CHAR(8))”

Comment: A new error now with CONVERT(colDate, CHAR(8)): Truncated incorrect char(8) value:'200910101...'

Answer (score 1):

Use a sub-select in your update (untested, and I've been using Firebird for too long, so someone check me here).

```
UPDATE MyTable AS TUpdate
SET MyNewField = (SELECT SUBSTRING(TSub.MyDateColumn,0,8) 
                  FROM MyTable AS TSub 
                  WHERE TSub.MyID = TUpdate.MyID);
```

As for future inserts correctly extracting the date, you're going to have to create a trigger on insert to extract the date for that record.

Comment: Not working either. I am getting complaints about using AS in the FROM clause...which is peculiar. Maybe they aren't allowed in UPDATE statements?

Comment: That's odd, but you could try without. It might be able to disambiguate the table in the sub-select from TUpdate if you can get the TUpdate alias to work...

Answer (score 0):

Need to use a subselect.

UPDATE someTable set timestamp = (SELECT SUBSTRING(colData, 0, 8) FROM someOriginalTable);

**EDIT** lc got me by a few seconds!

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tbl
SET
   newDateField = SUBSTRING(CAST(sourceCol AS varchar), 0, 8)
```