# Updating multiple rows in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update multiple rows in one table in MySQL database by doing this. And its not working.

```
$query = "UPDATE cart SET cart_qty='300' WHERE cart_id = '21';
          UPDATE cart SET cart_qty='200' WHERE cart_id = '23';
          UPDATE cart SET cart_qty='100' WHERE cart_id = '24';";
mysql_query($query,$link);// $link is specified above
```

Anyone know what is wrong with this.

Comment: Are you using mysql or mysqli?

Comment: Looks like three separate (yet structural identical) queries to me. Why do you want to send them as one statement instead of using e.g. a prepared statement three times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> mysql_query() sends a unique query (**multiple queries are not supported**)

The `;` separates SQL statements, so you need to separate the queries if you want to continue using the `mysql_query` function...

Comment: well i know you can run multiple queries of INSERT

Comment: Mutliple queries of insert tend to be concatenated series of value sets, combined by a comma: INSERT INTO cart (id,cart_qty) VALUES (21,300),(23,200),(24,100);

Comment: if i paste that query in phpMyadmin in SQL tab it work. Any ideas how phpMyadmin makes it work?

Comment: @Ross: Because phpMyAdmin allows multiple queries.  PHP doesn't, because of SQL injection attacks: http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 3):

`mysql_query` can't use multiple queries.

The easiest thing is to just run them separately. I believe you can do multi query but I haven't tried it.

```
$updateArray = array(21=>300,23=>200,24=>100);
foreach($updateArray as $id=>$value)
{
    $query = "UPDATE cart SET cart_qty='$value' WHERE cart_id = '$id'";
    mysql_query($query,$link);// $link is specified above
}
```

This will accept a combination of IDs and their corresponding cart value. Looping though, it builds the query and executes it. The array can then come from a variety of sources (results from another query, form inputs or, as in this case, hard-coded values)

Update:

If you really need to execute all in one, heres the PHP info on multi query:

[mysqli::multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
UPDATE table
  SET col1 = CASE id
    WHEN id1 THEN id1_v1,
    WHEN id2 THEN id2_v1
  END
  col2 = CASE id
    WHEN id1 THEN id1_v2,
    WHEN id2 THEN id2_v2
  END
  WHERE id IN (id1, id2)
```

This example shows updating two different columns in two different rows so you can expand this to more rows and columns by cludging together a query like this. There might be some scaling issues that makes the case statement unsuitable for a very large number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to send them as separate queries. Why not add the queries as strings to an array, then iterate through that array sending each query separtely?

Also check [this thread for another idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the best method.. But if you need to do multiple queries you could use something like...

```
function multiQuery($sql) 
{
  $query_arr  =  explode(';', $sql);

  foreach ($query_arr as $query)
  {
    mysql_query($query);
  }
}
```

another example of a helper query

```
function build_sql_update($table, $data, $where)
{

  $sql  =  '';

  foreach($data as $field => $item)
  {
    $sql .=  "`$table`.`$field` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($item)."',";
  }

  // remove trailing ,
  $sql  =  rtrim($sql, ',');

  return 'UPDATE `' . $table .'` SET '.$sql . ' WHERE ' .$where;
}

echo build_sql_update('cart', array('cart_qty' => 1), 'cart_id=21');
```