# How to run multiple Update Queries in single statement in PHP and mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to run the multiple queries in single statement how to do this.

Comment: inserts,selects,updates,replaces what kind of query's?

Comment: What kind of multiple queries? Multiple inserts in the same table: possible. Combination of different type of queries: not possible within php.

Comment: @Lawrence and @gnur As the question titled He is asking for `update` query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Updates in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you will have to use mysqli instead of mysql.

Please refer to the following

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Answer (score 4):

You can run multiple queries using [mysqli::multi_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

as the `mysql_` function family does not provide feature to execute multiple queries in once.