# two query updates doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

hi guys I got a little problem while I am was trying to updates my table. 
I just explain you my situation:
index.php

```
 <?php
          $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `references` ORDER BY `ID` ASC") or die(mysql_error());
while($referenc = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        echo '

        <tr>    

               <td>'.$referenc['name'].'</td>
               <td>'.$referenc['url'].'</td>
               <td>'.$referenc['date'].'</td>
               <td><a href="updatetest.php?id=' . $referenc['ID'] . '&move=up&position=' . $referenc['position'] . '">up</a></td>
               <td><a href="updatetest.php?id=' . $referenc['ID'] . '&move=down&position=' . $referenc['position'] . '">down</a></td> 
               <td><a href="showrefer.php?id=' . $referenc['ID'] . '">edit</a></td>
        </tr>    

            ';  
    }  


          ?>
```

how you can see I have there two links for up and down.
after click on one of that link I am going on updatetest.php

updaterest.php
f.e

```
move = up
position = 2;
id = 2;



  <?php
            $move = $_GET['move'];

             if($move == "up"){
                    $getcurrentid = $_GET['id'];
                                $moveup = $_GET['position']-1;

                $getprevposition = $_GET['position']-1;
                $position = $_GET['position'];

               $query = mysql_query("UPDATE `references` SET  `position`  = '$moveup' WHERE `references`.`ID`='$getcurrentid'") or die(mysql_error());

$query2 = mysql_query("UPDATE `references` SET  `position`  = '$position' WHERE `references`.`position`='$getprevposition'") or die(mysql_error());

              }
              else{echo'down';}

              ?>
```

Now it doing always just one update if I comment first update second one is working fine if I comment second update first one is working fine but if I uncomment it and wanna do it together its always doing just one update. I looking for some way how to do 2 updates in same time 
any ideas ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580854/how-to-run-multiple-update-queries-in-single-statement-in-php-and-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the queries in another order. `$moveup` and `$getprevposition` have the **same** value, so you are currently doing something like this

- change position to `new` where `id = x`
- change position to `old` where `position = new`

Since you just changed `position` to `new`, the second `WHERE` will catch the item you already edited (and undo your edit). Instead, you should do it like this

- change position to `old` where `position = new`
- change position to `new` where `id = x`

Now you don't have a conflict, as the row you really want to change doesn't yet have `position = new`.