# Update a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, insert-update

I have a table `table1` with three columns and a bunch of rows:

```
[key_col|col_a|col_b]
```

I want to update col_a with a set of values (i.e. leaving `col_b` unchanged), something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 AS t1 (key_col, col_a) VALUES ("k1", "foo"), ("k2", "bar");
```

But it doesn't work, how do I do this?

Comment: **UPDATE** the answer at was what I was looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql

Comment: `UPDATE table1 SET col_a='new' WHERE key_col='key';`

Answer (score 128):

You have to use UPDATE instead of INSERT:

- [UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

**For Example:**

```
UPDATE table1 SET col_a='k1', col_b='foo' WHERE key_col='1';
UPDATE table1 SET col_a='k2', col_b='bar' WHERE key_col='2';
```

Comment: so you are saying that i need to write one update query for each row I want to update?

Comment: Read this article for multiple rows update:

http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/articles/sql/update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-and-a-single-sql-query/

Comment: The link `Update Multiple Rows With Different Values and a Single SQL Query` is broken. Fix or remove please.

Comment: You can use a batch from your client application .

Answer (score 12):

```
UPDATE table1 SET col_a = 'newvalue'
```

Add a `WHERE` condition if you want to only update some of the rows.

Comment: could you give an example where multiply rows are updated in same query

Comment: This would update all rows. Use a where to limit this to less rows.

Answer (score 6):

This is what I did for bulk update:

```
UPDATE tableName SET isDeleted = 1 where columnName in ('430903GW4j683537882','430903GW4j667075431','430903GW4j658444015')
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to fill all the column:

```
update 'column' set 'info' where keyID!=0;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update data you should use `UPDATE` command instead of `INSERT`