# Mysql update function

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have created a form that submits to the mysql database. Now what I am trying to do is get it to update. The bit I'm having trouble with is the update query below, I just can not figure out where I am going wrong.

```
 <?php
/*
Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password)
*/
include 'db.php';

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['title']);
$price = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['price']);
$sqm = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['sqm']);
$sqm_land = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['sqm_land']);
$type = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['type']);
$area = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['area']);
$location = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['location']);
$bedroom = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['bedroom']);
$terrace = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['terrace']);
$orientation = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['orientation']);
$water = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['water']);
$seaview = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['seaview']);
$pool = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['pool']);
$ownerinfo = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['ownerinfo']);
$gaddress = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['gaddress']);
$description = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['description']);




// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "update INTO property (title, price, sqm, sqm_land, type, area, location, bedroom, terrace, orientation, water, seaview, pool, ownerinfo, gaddress, description) VALUES 
('$title', '$price', '$sqm', '$sqm_land', '$type', '$area', '$location', '$bedroom', '$terrace', '$orientation', '$water', '$seaview', '$pool', '$ownerinfo', '$gaddress', '$description' )";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records updated successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: You're already checking for errors with MySQL, but not with PHP http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and Lord knows what's in here `db.php`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update mysql column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503824/update-mysql-column)

Comment: *Teach a person how to fish* obviously did nothing here.

Comment: @Machavity Had I known beforehand, I'd of closed it in one go. I guess in trying to teach someone "how to fish" wasn't enough. I had to literally pull the fish out of the river myself. People are so in a hurry to eat before the dinner bell even rings.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's all good. And here's your [dinner bell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x8PWHOVYhI8) ;)

Comment: @Machavity *heh heh*, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong syntax for UPDATE.

Read the manual:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/update.html

What you're using is INSERT syntax. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html

Example from the manual:

```
UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1, col2 = col1;
```

and use a `WHERE` clause, otherwise you will be updating your entire db.

Example from the manual:

```
UPDATE items,month SET items.price=month.price
WHERE items.id=month.id;
```

So in your case and for example (fill in the rest):

```
UPDATE property SET title = '$title', price = '$price' ... WHERE column = ?
```

- `column` being the column name you want to target and the `?` being the row.

Your `mysqli_error($link)` would have thrown you something about it.

Sidenote: *"Teach a person how to fish, rather than throwing them a fish"*.

However, if the goal here is to INSERT, then you need to use `INSERT INTO table` and not `UPDATE INTO table`.

Also make sure your form uses a POST method and that all POST arrays contain values.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

Footnotes:

The MySQL API used to connect with in `db.php` is unknown. Make sure you are using the same API you are using to query with, being `mysqli_`. Different APIs do not intermix.

Comment: What am I, chopped liver here?

Comment: Hello, thanks sorry I totally missed your post. How can I put a Column / row down when it will be different each time?

Comment: @stephenaxe18 Sorry, I don't know what you mean by that.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect, it should be formatted like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE property SET title='$title'";
```

You'll have to add all the name/value pairs separated by commas since I only included 'title.'

Comment: I have just altered that. Worked great thanks apart from its updated all the other pages to the same. Any ideas on how to only update that one page?

Comment: @stephenaxe18 *"Any ideas on how to only update that one page?"* - I gave you answer already. You waiting for the other guy to grab what I have in mine to answer you?