# how to update a value in specific column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I would like to update value in productcatergory from bike to bikes in id 1 (row)

```
mysql> select * from productsale;
+----+------------------+--------+------------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+------------+
| id | productcatergory | color  | productname      | standardcost | dealerprice | salesamount | taxamount | orderdate  |
+----+------------------+--------+------------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+---------
|  1 | bike             | yellow | road-550-w,38    |          413 |         419 |         699 |        56 | 2015-05-25 |
|  2 | bikes            | black  | Road-650,58      |          413 |         419 |         699 |        56 | 2015-05-10 |
|  3 | components       | black  | HL Road Frame,44 |          413 |         419 |         699 |        56 | 2015-04-29 |
+----+------------------+--------+------------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+---------
```

kindly help me how to do?

Comment: Come on, you can do this yourself, at least try something. [That](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)'s worth a read for you.

Comment: If you are encountering an issue with performing this update that hasn't been covered by another question -which I doubt, it's definitely worth some searching- then please include the issue's details and what you've tried.

Comment: This is very specific, just a simple `UPDATE` with `WHERE id=1`. But your question might actually be something more than just _I want to update `bike` to `bikes` in id 1.._ Maybe something like _**How do I find all Id that have almost similar value like `bike` and `bikes` and update them to `bikes` or all id with almost similar value like `component` and `components` and update them all to `components` without having to search and update one by one?**_ .. .then that's a different question altogether..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update a column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503824/update-a-column-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to read the link provided by sticky bit.
Following is one way to update column in specific row:

```
UPDATE productsale
SET productcatergory = 'bikes'
WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: thanks for the help it worked. i have tried in different formats but i didn't work.I have doubt . suppose if want to change name on productcatergory  to productcategory. how can i do

Comment: For changing column name, you may use Alter Table command. Pls read docs of sql on this. And try to read tutorials first.