# pass column in INSERT query

Tags: mysql, insert

I want to update and insert to (in 1 query) my table. I've 1 new row and 2 old records.
I use this query ([topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql/3466#3466)):

```
INSERT INTO table (id, title, url) VALUES (1, "test", "http://"), (2, [it is an old record. I don't want to change its title], "https://"), (3, "helloworld", "mms://") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE title = VALUES(title), url = VALUES(url)
```

I don't want to change the second record (`id = 2`) `title` column, but if I put `NULL`, `DEFAULT` or `title` after comma, `title` will change to `NULL` (also if i put nothing after comma, an error will occur)

What can I do? should I use 2 or more queries?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, title, url) VALUES (1, "test", "http://"), (2, "", "https://"), (3, "helloworld", "mms://") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE title = IF(VALUES(title)="",title,VALUES(title)), url = VALUES(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% clear on your goal but could you not nest a SELECT that would pull back the old title for in place of the text in square brackets?