# unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING error

Tags: php, mysql, select

i've been staringly blanky at this error and can't seem to know what the problem is.When i run the query i get this error:

> unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING
>   at this line:

```
$sqlupdate1 = "UPDATE table SET commodity_quantity=$qty WHERE user=$rows['user'] ";
```

Comment: `$sqlupdate1 = "UPDATE table SET commodity_quantity=$qty WHERE user=$rows[user]";`

Comment: See the [chapter on variable parsing in strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing). And let's hope you sanitized these values before interpolating them into your query instead of using prepared statements.

Comment: In my case, I had the query in [HEREDOC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) string syntax, and indented the closing tag. It's allowed now in PHP 8+, but the project was on PHP 7.2. (Fetch API returned 500. It's nice to have log to at least Google things.)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

try this

```
echo $sqlupdate1 = "UPDATE table SET commodity_quantity=$qty WHERE user='".$rows['user']."' ";
```

Comment: thanks,it worked.but now let's say i want to updat more than one row how do i do that because this code doesn't seem to work:

echo $sqlupdate1 = "UPDATE table SET commodity_quantity=$qty AND name=$name WHERE user='".$rows['user']."' ";

Answer (score 14):

Try

```
$sqlupdate1 = "UPDATE table SET commodity_quantity=$qty WHERE user={$rows['user']} ";
```

You need curly brackets for array access in double quoted strings.

Comment: you dont need to add curly braces. you can simply omit the single quotes.

Comment: Move the bracket in front of the dollar sign

Answer (score 8):

Use { before $ sign. And also add addslashes function to escape special characters.

```
$sqlupdate1 = "UPDATE table SET commodity_quantity=".$qty."WHERE user=".addslashes($rows['user'])."'";
```

Comment: Queries params must be escaped with appropriate funcs like PDO::quote() or mysqli_real_esape_string(), not addslashes()

Answer (score 2):

In my case, heredoc caused the issue. There is no problem with PHP version 7.3 up. Howerver, it error with PHP 7.0.33 if you use heredoc with space.

My example code

```
$rexpenditure = <<<Expenditure
                  <tr>
                      <td>$row->payment_referencenumber</td>
                      <td>$row->payment_requestdate</td>
                      <td>$row->payment_description</td>
                      <td>$row->payment_fundingsource</td>
                      <td>$row->payment_agencyulo</td>
                      <td>$row->payment_agencyproject</td>
                      <td>$$row->payment_disbustment</td>
                      <td>$row->payment_payeename</td>
                      <td>$row->payment_processpayment</td>
                  </tr>
Expenditure;
```

It will error if there is a space on PHP 7.0.33.

Comment: "It will error if there is a space on PHP 7.0.33."  Space Where?

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to.

```
<?php
$sqlupdate1 = "UPDATE table SET commodity_quantity=".$qty."WHERE user=".$rows['user'];
?>
```

There was syntax error in your query.

Comment: thanks,it worked.but now let's say i want to update more than one row how do i do that because this code doesn't seem to work:

echo $sqlupdate1 = "UPDATE table SET commodity_quantity=$qty AND name=$name WHERE user='".$rows['user']."' ";

Comment: For that see this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql
and
http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlupdate.php

Answer (score -1):

My issue was also within the heredoc. I had it within an if/then statement and the closing bracket directly after the semicolon. So I moved the closing bracket to its own line and issue was fixed.

I changed:

```
... ;}
```

to:

```
... ;
}
```