# syntax error when I add Link

Tags: php

I try to get it fixed, but am still getting the following Parse error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE,
 expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in
```

this is the line 13:

```
<?php
  if ($fruitdata['fruit'] == "") {
    print "N/A <a href="./add.php?id=<?php print $fruitdata['id']; ?>">Edit</a>"; }
  else {
    print $fruitdata['fruit'];
  }
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [unexpected T\_ENCAPSED\_AND\_WHITESPACE, expecting T\_STRING or T\_VARIABLE or T\_NUM\_STRING error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583035/unexpected-t-encapsed-and-whitespace-expecting-t-string-or-t-variable-or-t-num)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape your double quotes and concatenate your string to your variables:

```
<td><?php if ($fruitdata['fruit'] == "") { print "N/A <a href=\"./add.php?id=". $fruitdata['id']."\">Edit</a>"; } else { print $fruitdata['fruit']; } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Expert one!

Comment: No problem. Be sure to mark this as correct if it was what you were looking for xD

Answer (score 0):

Multiple syntax errors. This should set you straight:

```
<td><?php
if ($fruitdata['fruit'] == "") {
    print 'N/A <a href=./add.php?id='.$fruitdata['id'].'">Edit</a>"';
}else{
    print $fruitdata['fruit'];
}?>
```

Comment: Thank you @Samuel Cook! Very helpful. I like stackoverflow! on my fb page!