# Parse Error: (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE)

Tags: php, mysql

```
include 'connect.php';
     if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT users (user_name, user_pass) VALUES (mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['user_name'], sha1($_POST['user_pass']")) 
     {
            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $user_name, $user_pass);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
     }
```

I get this error on the line of code above, I've been staring at it for ages but can't figure out what's wrong. I'm new to PHP, MySQL and HTML. Please help me.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\signup.php on line 77
```

Comment: its due to the improper concatenation on ur query..check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583035/unexpected-t-encapsed-and-whitespace-expecting-t-string-or-t-variable-or-t-num

Comment: Your code contains multiple errors, you should read more about PHP's syntaxis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good thing is you are trying to prepare, the bad news is you doing it wrong:

```
$username = $_POST['user_name'];
$password = $_POST['user_pass'];

$query = "INSERT users (user_name, user_pass) VALUES (?,  sha1(?)) ";
/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

**issues:**

- `mysql_real_escape_string` is deprecated
- `mysqli_real_escape_string` would be useless
- Your string concatenation is wrong

Comment: This is what I get with that script:
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in C:\xampp\htdocs\signup.php on line 85

Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in C:\xampp\htdocs\signup.php on line 86

Comment: @user71032 oops, see my edit