# Mysql join few queries in one?

Tags: mysql

Can I combine two queries like this

```
first: UPDATE table SET col1=1 WHERE id='x'; 

second: UPDATE table SET col1=0 WHERE id='y';
```

can I join these queries in one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE table
SET col1 = CASE id WHEN 'x' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
WHERE id IN ('x','y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this sql query:

```
UPDATE table
SET col1 = 
CASE id 
WHEN 'x' THEN 1 
WHEN 'y' THEN 0 
END
WHERE id IN ('x','y');
```

Also see [Multiple Updates in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table
SET col1 = (id = 'x')
WHERE id IN ('x','y');
```