# Kohana Edit Values Into Database

Tags: php, forms, kohana

I'm trying to edit values in a database, and I'm getting the following error:

```
Call to a member function values() on a non-object
```

Controller

```
public function action_options() {

    $this->template->styles = array(
        'style' => 'style',
        'acp' => 'acp'
    );

    $options = ORM::factory('option')->find_all()->as_array('option_name','option_value');

    $this->template->content = View::factory('default/admin/options')
        ->bind('options', $options);
}

    public function action_savesettings() {

    $options = ORM::factory('option')->find_all()->as_array('option_name','option_name');

    $options->values($this->request->post());

    $errors = array();

    try {

        $options->save();

        $this->request->redirect('acp/options');

   } catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $ex) {

       $errors = $ex->errors('validation');

   }

    $this->template->content = View::factory('default/admin/options')
        ->bind('options', $options)
        ->bind('errors', $errors);
}
```

View

```
<?php $errors = isset($errors) ? $errors : array(); ?>
<?php echo Form::open('acp/savesettings'); ?>
Site Name: <?php echo Form::input('site_name', $options['site_name'], array('id' => 'acp-sitename')); ?><br />
<?php echo Form::submit('submit', 'Submit', array('id' => 'acp-submit')); ?>
<?php echo Form::close(); ?>
```

My table is like:

```
option_id   option_name     option_value
```

I'm not sure how to approach this, since I'm accessing and editing the values with $options[''].

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to set values not on `Model` class instance but on array. You can see that by `var_dump($options);` before setting values on it.

`values()` method is the method of `ORM` class.

Also to get `ORM` class instance you should call `find()` method, nor `find_all()`.

`find()` returns `ORM` class instance and loads ONE RECORD from database into it. Then you can assign values to it by calling `values()`.

`find_all()` returns `Database_Result` class instance - it's a collection of found records. In Kohana you can treat them as an array.

Here is what you need write

```
$option = ORM::factory('option')->find();

$option->values($this->request->post());
```

Note that you change ONLY ONE database record. To change more than one record at one database request you will need to call this code for every record or use `DB:update()` method to create query.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, You want to modify site settings. So, your code should looks like this:

```
// search for changing option 
$option = ORM::factory('option')->where('option_name', '=', 'site_name')->find();
// set new value
$option->set('option_value', $this->request->post('site_name'));
// update value, handle validation errors, etc
try {...}
```

If you want to update a few records, you should use Query Builder or `DB::query()` with a special [multiple query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql).