# Multiple Updates using the Insert Method - Ignoring Unique Records

Tags: mysql

I want to update multiple records at once using a similar method to this:

[Multiple Updates in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql)

but is there a MySQL command to ignore anything that isnt a duplicate? Something like

```
ON DUPLICATE UPDATE ON UNIQUE IGNORE
```

(ive just made this code up btw)

?

Comment: Have a look at [insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/)

Comment: this is the exact opposite of what i want to do - he is trying to skip the duplicate entries, whereas i want to skip anything that isnt a duplicate entry.

Comment: Ah ok, thought that was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't we use a single UPDATE command that can update MULTIPLE rows!

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET Col2 = CASE
  WHEN Col1 = 1 THEN 'new Value From someplace';
  WHEN Col1 = 2 THEN 'War and Peace';
  ELSE Col2
END
```

The **ELSE Col2** is very important, otherwise you will overwrite the rest of the table with NULL.

You can add more **CASE** blocks to update more columns.

By doing this you can avoid the headache of INSERTING UNIQUE records.

Hope this helps.

Comment: excellent, thanks! - im unfamiliar with the CASE / WHEN / THEN syntax, but this does exactly what im trying to do!