# MySQL Multi-row Update Using One Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL Table as the image below:
[image]

I have my form edit as the image below:
[image]

(Path column on the Database selects the Category as on the image 2).

How do I run a multi-row MySQL Update query for this using PDO prepared statement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple Updates in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql)

Comment: YES, they are dependent on WHERE link_id IN (...). Something of that nature.
@jli I guess you should check to see if they have PDO on just MySQL on them before you mark down.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually just use MySQL's `CASE` to update multiple rows. This can be done for multiple columns as well, and the statements aren't that tough to generate in PHP.

```
UPDATE `links` SET `name` = CASE `link_id`
    WHEN '36' THEN 'Mc'
    WHEN '37' THEN 'Mc'
    WHEN '38' THEN 'sdfghjkl'
    WHEN '39' THEN 'r5tyuikolp;['
END, `path` = CASE `link_id`
    WHEN '36' THEN '2'
    WHEN '37' THEN '1'
    WHEN '38' THEN '2'
    WHEN '39' THEN '7'
END WHERE `link_id` IN ('36','37','38','39');
```

Comment: Thanks for the lead. Assuming I am to run this same query to loop through like 1000 rows, how do I go about running the loop and then this query to achieve the same result as this example's solution you've provided.