# Update multiple rows in a single MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run this:

```
UPDATE test 
SET col2=1 WHERE col1='test1', 
SET col2=3 WHERE col1='test2';
```

The error I am getting:

```
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
```

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `col1` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `col2` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`col1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

It’s something about `,` at the end of the first row. When I changed it to `;`, it didn’t recognize col2. How can I do this in one query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Updates in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql). You'll find your answer there

Comment: yeah i know that solution, but in my case, every rows will already exist in table(it doesnt need to be inserted), so it would always run ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE and make everything a lot slower.

Comment: I can't understand what do you mean. Use the `INSERT` command when you need to update and that's all. If you use a primary key it won't be much slower

Comment: ok, i will do that if nobody will suggest better solution, thank you

Comment: Just to make it clear, if you use your primary key (not just col1 = "test") it will be pretty fast.

Answer (score 40):

This is most clear way

```
UPDATE test
SET col2 = CASE col1
WHEN 'test1' THEN 1
WHEN 'test2' THEN 3
WHEN 'test3' THEN 5
END,
colx = CASE col1
WHEN 'test1' THEN 'xx'
WHEN 'test2' THEN 'yy'
WHEN 'test3' THEN 'zz'
END
WHERE col1 IN ('test1','test2','test3')
```

Comment: Isn't the WHERE-part unnecessary?

Comment: Without the WHERE, the CASE will fall thru returning null (probably not what anyone wants). I believe adding an "ELSE col2" is safeish without the WHERE, but will lead to uncessary updates.

Comment: @Clox also, if you don't include the `WHERE` clause then mysql has to go through **each** row to check. Sure there will be no performance issue with this example but imagine if you have 1000 rows and you only want to update 2 rows.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using INSERT-ODKU (ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE), because that supports to update multiple rows.

Make sure that the values of all PK columns are in the VALUES().

Where feasible, generate the SQL with data from a slave.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `CASE` on this

```
UPDATE test 
SET col2 = CASE WHEN col1 = 'test1' THEN 1 ELSE 3 END 
WHERE col1 IN ('test1', 'test2')
```

or `IF` (for `MySQL` only)

```
UPDATE test 
SET col2 = IF(col1 = 'test1', 1, 3)
WHERE col1 IN ('test1', 'test2')
```

Comment: i would like to add a lot more rows in future and with more columns :( I just gave simple example to my problem.

Comment: @Itay what do you mean by flexible?

Comment: I mean that it will be very hard to update 100 rows like that.

Comment: @user2618929 then build a dynamic sql.

Comment: @Itay so can you provide an alternative?

Comment: See the duplicated post for a better solution

Comment: @Itay where is the duplicate post ?

Answer (score 1):

alternatively when the construct with `cases` gets too unreadable, you could/should start a transaction and just do the updates sequentially.

this usually results in more straightforward sql, except if the first statements creates rows that then are matched by the second statement when they should not. however this is not the case in your example.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

`UPDATE col1` (static value), `col2` (static value), and `col3` (different values) `WHERE col4` has different values `AND col5` is static.

```
$someArray = ["a","b","c"];
$anotherArray = [1,2,3];

$sql = "UPDATE table SET col1 = '$staticValue1', col2 = '$staticValue2', col3 = CASE col4";
    $sqlEnd = " END WHERE col4 IN (";
    $seperator = ",";
    for ( $c = 0; $c < count($someArray); $c++ ) {
       $sql .= " WHEN " . "'" . $someArray[$c] . "'" . " THEN " . $anotherArray[$c];
       if ( $c === count($someArray) - 1 ) { 
          $separator = ") AND col5 = '$staticValue5'";
       }
        $sqlEnd .= "'" . $someArray[$c] . "'" . $seperator;

    }
    $sql .= $sqlEnd;
    $retval = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql);
    if(! $retval ) {
        /* handle error here */
    }
```

And the output string for MySql query would be something like this:

```
UPDATE table SET col1 = '1', col2 = '2', col3 = CASE col4 WHEN 'a' THEN 1 WHEN 'b' THEN 2 WHEN 'c' THEN 3 END WHERE col4 IN ('a','b','c') AND col5 = 'col5'
```

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL8 it can be done smarter,
but also consider creating a temporary result set, inside the SQL,
to JOIN with:

```
UPDATE MyTable t JOIN (
SELECT 'v1a' AS c1, 'v1b' AS c2 
UNION ALL SELECT 'v2a', 'v2b' 
UNION ALL SELECT 'v3a', 'v3b'
) AS u USING (c1) 
SET t.c2 = u.c2
```