# MySQL combine two UPDATE Queries in one Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I want to update status, but using one query !!

```
UPDATE myTable SET `status` = 0 WHERE `name` IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
UPDATE myTable SET `status` = 1 WHERE `name` NOT IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

Comment: use `case when` statement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update multiple rows in a single MySQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18802671/update-multiple-rows-in-a-single-mysql-query)

Comment: Try with sql union or union all in between two queries

Comment: try this.  `UPDATE myTable SET status = IF(name IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),1,0)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **[CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)** statement.

```
UPDATE myTable
SET status = (CASE
                  WHEN `name` IN ('a','b','c','d') THEN '0'
                  WHEN `name` NOT IN ('a','b','c','d') THEN '1'
              END);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make 'status' datatype **boolean**, **default value 0** and for "`name NOT IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')`"

use

```
UPDATE myTable SET `status` = 1 WHERE `name` NOT IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
```

You do not have to run two queries.

Comment: @TalalFarhat you are using UPDATE to update status , if status update is not possible after first how you are doing it ? or you are facing problem when you are using boolean for status ?