# Update multiple rows with one query in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The following Rails code results in 6 queries

```
people = { 1 => { "name" => "David" }, 2 => { "name" => "Jeremy" }, 3 => { "name" => "Tom" } }
Person.update(people.keys, people.values)
```

It will do TWO queries per updated row. One select and one update.

Is there a way to do the same task in Rails 4 with only one query (or only two queries)?

There are some information here on how to do it in MySQL, but not Rails:
 [Multiple Updates in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql#3466)

Thanks.

Comment: short answer is no. because every transaction has to be atomic and isolated in a relational database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, but not for the reason @Sam D gave.

It's because if you go through `ActiveRecord`, it's because you want to run validations, callbacks, etc. on the objects being updated. These validations and callbacks are not defined for a collection of objects.

You might say, "I don't care if they run." And that's fine. That's why rails gives you the ability to mass update through SQL directly.

Comment: Kaleidoscope, thank you for your explanation. As you mentioned, I don't care if validations and callbacks run. Do you have a link/reference for mass update through SQL in rails? Thanks.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all