# Insert add row feature in PHP form and linking it to the database

Tags: php

How can i include add row feature in my PHP form and insert additionally added rows into the database? I havetried using the HTML code for button to insert additional rows but it does not work. Do i need to use javascript?? Please help me
    This is my HTML code. Row is not added after hitting add button.

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var i=1;
    function addRow()
    {
          var tbl = document.getElementById('table2');
          var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
          var iteration = lastRow - 1;
          var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

          var firstCell = row.insertCell(0);
          var el = document.createElement('input');
          el.type = 'text';
          el.name = 'activityname_' + i;
          el.id = 'activityname_' + i;
          firstCell.appendChild(el);

          var secondCell = row.insertCell(1);
          var el2 = document.createElement('input');
          el2.type = 'text';
          el2.name = 'unit_' + i;
          el2.id = 'unit_' + i;
          secondCell.appendChild(el2);

          var thirdCell = row.insertCell(2);
          var el3 = document.createElement('input');
          el3.type = 'text';
          el3.name = 'weightage_' + i;
          el3.id = 'weightage_' + i;
          thirdCell.appendChild(el3);

          var thirdCell = row.insertCell(3);
          var el4 = document.createElement('input');
          el4.type = 'text';
          el4.name = 'per100_' + i;
          el4.id = 'per100_' + i;
          fourthCell.appendChild(el4);

          var thirdCell = row.insertCell(4);
          var el5 = document.createElement('input');
          el5.type = 'text';
          el5.name = 'per75_' + i;
          el5.id = 'per75_' + i;
          fifthCell.appendChild(el5);

          var thirdCell = row.insertCell(5);
          var el6 = document.createElement('input');
          el6.type = 'text';
          el6.name = 'per50_' + i;
          el6.id = 'per50_' + i;
          sixthCell.appendChild(el6);

          var thirdCell = row.insertCell(6);
          var el7 = document.createElement('input');
          el7.type = 'text';
          el7.name = 'per75_' + i;
          el7.id = 'per75_' + i;
          seventhCell.appendChild(el7);
         // alert(i);
          i++;
          frm.h.value=i;
        //  alert(i);
    }
    </script>
    <?php
    error_reporting(0);
    include ('includes/workplan_func.php');
    ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css" />
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title> Workplan Detail Form </title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
    <img src="images/logo.jpg" width="305" height="108" />
    </div>
    <div id="Box">
      <ul>
       <li><a href="workplan.php">Workplan Detail</a></li>
      <li><a href="workprogress.php">Workplan Progress</a></li>
      <li><a href="pbis_form.php">PBIS</a></li>
      <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="rightcol">
      <div id="Content" align="center">
    <h1 align="center">Workplan Detail Form</h1>
    <div id="table1" class="container" align="left">    
                //<form name="frm" id="frm" action="includes/workplan_func.php" method="post">
                <table width="398" height="118" border="0" align="left" >

                  <td>
                        <tr>
                            <td > <p>Division Name:</p> </td>
                            <td><input name="divisionname" type="text" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><p>Division Chief: </p></td>
                            <td>   
                            <input type="text" name="divisionchief" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><p> Period:  </p> </td>
                            <td>  
                            <input type="text" name="period" /></td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><p> Month:</p>  </td>
                            <td>  

                            <input type="month" name="month" /> </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>

                    </table>
                    </div>
                    <div id="table2">
                    <table border="1" align="center" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2" align="center"> SN </td>
                    <td rowspan="2" align="center"> Activity Name </td>
                    <td rowspan="2" align="center" > Unit </td>
                    <td rowspan="2" align="center"> Weightage </td>
                    <td colspan="4" align="center"> Performance Indicators(Percentage)
                    </td>
                 <tr>
                    <td align="center">100 </td>
                    <td align="center"> 75</td>
                    <td align="center"> 50 </td>
                    <td align="center"> <50 </td>
                 </tr>
                 <form name="frm" id="frm" action="includes/workplan_func.php" method="post">
                 <table border="1" align="center" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="table2">
                 <tr>
                 <td width:50px > </td>
                    <td> <input type="text" name="activityname_0" id="activityname_0" style="width:130px"/> </td>
                    <td> <input type="text" name="unit_0" id="unit_0" style="width:50px" /> </td>
                    <td> <input type="text" name="weightage_0" id="weightage_0" style="width:130px" /> </td>
                    <td> <input type="text" name="per100_0" id="per100_0" style="width:50px" /> </td>
                    <td> <input type="text" name="per75_0" id="per75_0" style="width:50px" /> </td>
                    <td> <input type="text" name="per50_0" ="per50_0" style="width:50px" /> </td>
                    <td> <input type="text" name="perless50_0" id="perless50_0" style="width:50px" /> </td>
                  </tr>


                  </table>
                  </div>


                  <div id="button">

                        <div align="center">  <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addRow();" />
                                              <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <label>
                        <input name="h" type="hidden" id="h" value="0" />
                        </label>
                        </form>
                 </body>
                 </html>
```

Comment: means you want to add multiple records at a time. right?

Comment: @Ranjith that's exactly what i want..

Comment: We cannot help you if you don't post your code so far. "Does not work" is not a description that helps here.

Comment: @Bishal_bh Refer [this](http://www.9lessons.info/2010/04/jquery-duplicate-field-form-submit-with.html) link to this functionality

Comment: This will help u exactly and yes u have to use javascript

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756282/php-mysql-insert-into-database/21756852#21756852

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just looking to add more than one value without having to iterate over the possible outputs again and again then a statement such as the following may help you assuming you are using MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO your_table (value1,value2,value3) VALUES (v1,v2,v3),(v1,v2,v3),(etc...)
```

If you are looking to simply add form fields to you HTML then you will want to look into some JavaScript/JQuery solution that gives you the visual appeal you are looking for.

You would need to create the code that dynamically forms the string in place of the `(v1,v2,v3),(v1,v2,v3),(etc...)` but that can be a simple foreach loop.

Hope this helps you out a little.