# Multiple records updating in single query using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Can any one help on this issue.When i'm trying to updating multiple record using catid(it contain same catid one or more) it is not updating results.

Below is the code

enter code here

```
<?php

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("db_name",$cnn) or die("Could not select examples");

    $sql="SELECT *
                    FROM `plannedbudgetstbl`
                    LEFT JOIN budget_categories ON plannedbudgetstbl.cat_id = budget_categories.cat_id
                    WHERE programid ='".$id."'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    // Count table rows 
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    ?>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">

    <table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
     <tr> 
    <td>
    <table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">


    <tr>
    <td align="center"><strong>budget</strong></td>

    </tr>
    <?php
    // Check if button name "submit" is active, do this 
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
         $budget = $_POST['budget'];


    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    $sql1="UPDATE plannedbudgetstbl SET budget='".$budget[$i]."' WHERE programid = '".$id[$![enter image description here][1]i]."'and cat_id='".$id[$i]."'";

    $result1=mysql_query($sql1);
    }
    }
    if(isset($result1)){
    header("location:budget-dispaly1.php");
    }
    ?>
    <?php
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td align="center"><?php $id[]=$rows['cat_id']; ?><?php echo $rows['cat_id']; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><input name="budget[]" type="text" id="budget" value="<?php echo $rows['budget']; ?>"></td>

    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="4" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>

    </table>
        </form>
```

Here is the update output
[image]

Comment: What's wrong with that output? What was the input?

Comment: Use the trick with INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql

Comment: When i click on submit .Records are not updated.it means update query is not executed.

Comment: You're not setting `$id[$i]` before the `UPDATE` query.

Comment: What is `$id[$![enter image description here][1]i]` supposed to be? It looks like you got some SO markup mixed up in there.

Comment: cat_id is not unique. we need to update query  based on cat_id.But cat_id have one or more records like cat_id 1 - 1345,1-32145 like that it is based on programid

Comment: Hi Barmar, oh sorry when i pasting here it is mixed up .
WHERE programid = 108688

Comment: but query look like this $sql="UPDATE plannedbudgetstbl SET budget='".$budget[$i]."' WHERE programid = 108688 and cat_id='".$id[$i]."'";

Comment: @MandaliVenkat Are you not allowed to edit your question?

Comment: Is $id a normal variable or an array? You first query selects rows where programid = $ id (not an array) while the update check for cat_id = $id[$i] (an array)