# Multiple Update - possible errors

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a function for executing multiple updates at one time.

I was inspired by example code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql?s=1%7C3.5261) :

```
INSERT INTO table (id,Col1,Col2) VALUES (1,1,1),(2,2,3),(3,9,3),(4,10,12)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Col1=VALUES(Col1),Col2=VALUES(Col2);
```

But the output of my function is like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (id,Col1,Col2) VALUES (1,1,1),(2,2,3),(3,9,3),(4,10,12)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=VALUES(id), Col1=VALUES(Col1), Col2=VALUES(Col2);
```

So I'm concerned that my output includes the primary key field between updates.

I tried the code and it seems to work well (including the primary key)
This can generate errors that I haven't met yet?
Do I have to delete the primary key from second part of the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to worry about the `id = VALUES(id)`, if `id` is a primary key and the only unique key on the table.  In this case, the `id` is used for matching, so the value doesn't change.

If you have multiple unique keys on the table, then this could be an issue.  If your data was:

```
id    col1    col2
 2       1       1
```

And you have a unique key on `(col1, col2)`, then when you insert `(1, 1, 1)`, the values will change to:

```
id    col1    col2
 1       1       1
```

Comment: So I can use this function only for updating tables with primary key on one field. Thanks