# Proper way to manipulate database

Tags: php, mysql

[My entry form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VTTO.png) I have an inventory database with tables like aluminium, iron etc... Each table contains a subcategory of items like aluminium_pala, iron_1.5inch and so on. The entry code is like this:

```
include("dbConnect.php");
$orderNo = $_POST["number"];

if(isset($_POST["mat1"])&&$_POST["mat1"]!=NULL)
{
    $mat1 = $_POST["mat1"];
    $selmat1 = $_POST["selmat1"];
    $amtmat1 = $_POST["amtmat1"];

    $query = "INSERT INTO $mat1 ($selmat1,orderNo) VALUES (-$amtmat1,$orderNo);";
    if(!($result = $mysqli->query($query)))
         print "<div class='error'>insertion failed. Check your data</div>";
}
if(isset($_POST["mat2"])&&$_POST["mat2"]!=NULL)
{
    $mat2 = $_POST["mat2"];
    $selmat2 = $_POST["selmat2"];
    $amtmat2 = $_POST["amtmat2"];

    $query = "INSERT INTO $mat2 ($selmat2,orderNo) VALUES (-$amtmat1,$orderNo);";
    if(!($result = $mysqli->query($query)))
         print "<div class='error'>insertion failed. Check your data</div>";
}... and it goes on till mat11
```

I am trying to collect each similar table (mat1, mat2..) and their corresponding item (selmat1, selmat2...) and bunch the all in one query. That is, instead of going

```
INSERT INTO al_openable (zPala,orderNo) VALUES (23,14); 
INSERT INTO al_openable (outer,orderNo) VALUES (50,14);
```

I am trying to execute it like

```
INSERT INTO al_openable (zPala,outer,orderNo) VALUES (23,50,14);
```

I need this to avoid duplicate foreign key entry(for $orderNo). One idea I've been considering is to use UPDATE if the order number is pre-existing. Do you guys think this is a good idea? And if so, what will be the best way to execute it? If not, how would a more experienced programmer solve this conundrum?

Comment: keep only one table with this fields: `zPala,outer,orderN` and then insert accordingly

Comment: Please read my question. I have that table already. The problem is bunching queries together for same tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question is related to your query: [Multiple Updates in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql)

You may use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in combination with INSERT statement.

Comment: Oh nice and simple solution. I couldn't find it anywhere. Thank you.