# updating multiple fields in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have the database as below

```
Name   id  Col1   
Row1   1    0      
Row2   2    1      
Row3   3    1
```

if i submit query...result should be as below

```
Name   id  Col1   
Row1   1    1       
Row2   2    0     
Row3   3    1
```

next

```
 Name   id  Col1   
    Row1   1    1       
    Row2   2    1     
    Row3   3    0
```

like so on...
finally

```
 Name   id  Col1   
        Row1   1    0       
        Row2   2    1     
        Row3   3    1
```

i tired CASE statement in mysql...but not worked

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql

Comment: where is your code which you have tried.?

Comment: UPDATE page SET STATUS = CASE id 
                          WHEN 0 THEN 1 
                          WHEN 1 THEN 0 
                          
                        END
                
             WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3);

its loop...wanna run in script

Comment: What will be your end result??