# PHP, MySQL Update multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, multiple-columns

```
$mengetotzut = 7','8','9','22','23','24','25 ;
$zutatiddd = 42','75','8','90','23','82','33 ;
$sql5= "UPDATE zutaten SET Menge=('$mengetotzut') WHERE Zutat_ID IN('$zutatiddd')";
 $run_query = mysqli_query($con,$sql5);
```

As SQL statement is looking like :

```
UPDATE zutaten SET Menge=('42','75','8','90','23','82','33') WHERE Zutat_ID IN('7','8','9','22','23','24','25')
```

What i am trying to do is to do is:

```
Update Menge='42' Where Zutat_ID is '7' AND Update Menge ='75' Where Zutat_ID = '8' ...
```

But in one SQL statement. Can someone tell me if this is possible and how can i do it?

Comment: why not use a foreach and loop over

Comment: @coder how can ai do this ?

Comment: You can't do a multiple update in one query. You can do a multiple insert with the clause "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" TO DO YOUR PURPOSE. You can find this explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql

Comment: With a simple for or foreach loop you can iterate over your $mengetotzut and $zutatiddd arrays. You cant execute a single sql statement for your purpose. you have to execute as many update statements, as items in your arrays.

Insert on duplicate key presumes a strictly normalized data structure. But have a try on SBO s comment.

Comment: @SBO yes you can, the second answer in the question linked shows you can using CASE.

Comment: You are right, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that both arrays have the same count, try the below

```
$count = 7;

for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
    $sql5= "UPDATE zutaten SET Menge=$mengetotzut[$i] WHERE Zutat_ID = $zutatiddd[$i]";
    $run_query = mysqli_query($con,$sql5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach loop

```
foreach( $mengetotzut as $index => $code ) {
$sql5= "UPDATE zutaten SET Menge=('$code') WHERE Zutat_ID = $zutatiddd[$index];
 $run_query = mysqli_query($con,$sql5);   
}
```

Comment: i use this in 
<?php foreach( $mengetotzut as $index => $code ) {
$sql5= "UPDATE zutaten SET Menge=('$code') WHERE Zutat_ID = $zutatiddd[$index];
 $run_query = mysqli_query($con,$sql5);   
} ?> 

and he shows me as error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `SQL` query like the following to `UPDATE` with one go:

```sql
UPDATE zutaten AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT 7 AS Zutat_ID, 42 AS Menge
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 8, 75
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 9, 8
) t2 ON t1.Zutat_ID = t2.Zutat_ID
SET t1.Menge = t2.Menge
```

Comment: the problem is that the number can change this because in my code i have more sql statements and the numbers can change that why i want to do it from variable

Answer (score 0):

What you are after is [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html), your query will look like this:

```
UPDATE zutaten SET Menge = CASE Zutat_ID
    WHEN 42 THEN 7
    WHEN 75 THEN 8
    WHEN 8 THEN 9
    WHEN ...
END WHERE Zutat_ID IN (42,75,8,...)
```

Comment: the problem is that the number can change this because in my code i have more sql statements and the numbers can change that why i want to do it from variable

Comment: @CristianCănănău great, so write it dynamically using variables. It's not hard to add a for loop that outputs the `WHEN THEN` part.

Comment: can you show me as code? my variable  $mengetotzut = 7','8','9','22','23','24','25 ; ---- is looking like this  and $zutatiddd = 42','75','8','90','23','82','33 ; ---- is looking like this

Comment: @CristianCănănău I'm not going to write your code for you, this isn't a code writing service. If you can't even write a basic for loop then go do some tutorials on **basic** PHP.

Comment: than how can i do this ? because i try more option and thy doesdn' work?