# How to execute multiple query update at the same time?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have this three lines, and the problem is that only the last one is updating. What am I doing wrong? What can I do to them to update all three at the same time?

```
$query = "UPDATE arak SET ara = '$konyha' WHERE ID = 1";
$query = "UPDATE arak SET ara = '$kugli' WHERE ID = 2";
$query = "UPDATE arak SET ara = '$ronk' WHERE ID = 3";
```

Comment: I believe this post already answers your question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Updates in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql)

Comment: you are just overriding the existing variable seems like . please add more example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should execute each single query otherwise you execute only the last  query assigned  at $query

```
$query = "UPDATE arak SET ara = '$konyha' WHERE ID = 1"; 
your_execute_command() ... ;
$query = "UPDATE arak SET ara = '$kugli' WHERE ID = 2";
your_execute_command() ... ;
$query = "UPDATE arak SET ara = '$ronk' WHERE ID = 3";
your_execute_command() ... ;
```

or could yuo ca use a single query with  a case clause

```
  UPDATE arak
  SET ara = case when ID = 1 then '$konyha' 
                 when ID = 2 then '$kugli'
                 when ID = 3 then '$ronk' 
            else ara
            end
```

Comment: @scaisEdge - else missed - THEN ara - OR WHERE id in (1,2,3)

Comment: @BerndBuffen  thanks for suggestion  added   else  too

Comment: Possibly the 2nd one would be faster if you also did `WHERE ID IN (1,2,3)` (right?)

Answer (score -1):

Just combine these queries in a single string separated by terminator and use:

```
mysqli_multi_query($connection,$query);
```