# Mysql update query for update all users data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want a Mysql query to update all users 'status' filed in 'user' table. I can update one user by running following query.

Table

[image]

**What I tried**

```
update user set status = 1 where id = 1 and type = 'viber'
```

Do I need to run the above query inside a loop to update all users data?

**I want a query like following**

```
update user set status = 1 where id = 1 and type = 'viber' and id = 2 and type = 'twitter' ..
```

your help is much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql

Comment: if you want to update all status in the table you need to remove your WHERE clause in your query something like this : UPDATE table_name SET Status = 1;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just

```
update user set status=1;
```

Updates your whole table.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just update the status for all records then below query is useful for that.

```
update user set status=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The  [WHERE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimizations.html)clause is used to extract only those records that fulfill a specified criterion. but here you don't want that .so just use this query to update all the records

```
update user set status=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

just use:

```
$update = mysqli_query("UPDATE user SET status = 1")or die(mysqli_error());
```

if this not works, you can select all data and then update each row by setting user id like this :

```
$select =  mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM user")or die(mysqli_error());
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    mysqli_query("UPDATE user SET status=1 WHERE id='$id' ");
}
```