# How do I update multiple rows in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I know this question may be asked too many times on these forums but I genuinely cannot find a solid answer. They all give different methods.

Anyway, I have this code to update one row:

```
$sql = "UPDATE $userName SET P1 = '$p1MON' WHERE day = 'MON1'";
```

Is it possible to update multiple rows in the same query? Something like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE $userName SET P1 = '$p1MON' WHERE day = 'MON1',
        UPDATE $userName SET P1 = '$p1TUE' WHERE day = 'TUE1',
        UPDATE $userName SET P1 = '$p1WED' WHERE day = 'WED1'";
```

Or, to update multiple rows in one query, do they have to share an identifier?

Thanks.

EDIT: A suggestion in the comments , doesn't seem to work...

```
$sql = "UPDATE $userName SET P1 = '$p1MON' WHERE day = 'MON1';
        UPDATE $userName SET P1 = '$p1TUE' WHERE day = 'TUE1';
        UPDATE $userName SET P1 = '$p1WED' WHERE day = 'WED1'";
```

Comment: not separate them by comma separate them by semicolon

Comment: Duplicate question, [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql)

Comment: See the new edit. Doesn't seem to work @MASIDDIQUI

Answer (score 10):

Use a `case` expression:

```
UPDATE $userName
SET P1 = case day
         when 'MON1' then '$p1MON'
         when 'TUE1' then '$p1TUE'
         when 'WED1' then '$p1WED'
         end
where day IN ('MON1', 'TUE1', 'WED1')
```

Comment: What exactly does a case expression do? I'd like to understand it.

Comment: For different day values, it returns different values. For day value 'MON1', it returns '$p1MON' etc.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for and it works great. Thanks. I'll accept the answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case

Comment: Hold on - what if I wanted a different column, rather than just P1? Would I require a new query? @jarlh

Comment: It depends on the situation. The WHERE clause decides which rows to update. If you want to update the same rows as before, you can simply add another column update to the statement. If you want other rows to be updated, I'd probably consider a separate UPDATE statement. (Depends on the table size, number of updated rows etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Depending you database engine you can try something like this

```
$sql = "UPDATE $userName SET P1 = '$p1MON' WHERE day = 'MON1'; UPDATE $userName SET P1 = '$p1TUE' WHERE day = 'TUE1'; UPDATE $userName SET P1 = '$p1WED' WHERE day = 'WED1'"
```

Or

```
$sql = "UPDATE $userName SET P1 = '$p1MON' WHERE day = 'MON1' go  UPDATE $userName SET P1 = '$p1TUE' WHERE day = 'TUE1' go  UPDATE $userName SET P1 = '$p1WED' WHERE day = 'WED1'"
```

Using ; or GO (depending of you database)  separate instructions  to execute then on "one query"

Answer (score 0):

is the field day a unique key field?

If so you can use *on duplicate key update* syntax.

```
INSERT INTO $userName(day, P1) VALUES
('MON1', '$p1MON'),
('TUE1', '$p1TUE'),
('WED1', '$p1WED')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE P1=VALUES(P1)
```