# Multiple update mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a problem with the following query:

```
insert into table
select *
from table
on duplicate key update field1 = field1 + 10
```

I'm trying to update a field in 1 table, of course I cannot use UPDATE statement because I need to update all the rows in the table.
When I try to execute the query mysql returns me the error:

```
ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'field1' in field list is ambiguous
```

"table" and "field1" are example names

--UPDATE--

the query could also be:

```
insert into table
select *
from table
where field2 < 1000
on duplicate key update field1 = field1 + 10
```

I even tryed:

```
update table
set field1 = field1 + 10
where field2 < 1000
```

But all the rows updated have field1 = 10, the sum doesn't work

Comment: What's wrong with `update table set field1 = field1 + 10`?  Without a WHERE clause, that'll update all the rows.

Comment: you should specify filed1 belong which table, because both of them has field1

Comment: @mj.84 exactly, is the same field of the same table to be updated

Comment: @Wyzard I cannot use update table because I need a where clause in other queries

Comment: Then use a WHERE clause in your other queries, but don't use it in this one.  Your reasons for avoiding UPDATE don't make any sense to me.

Comment: @big Find a answer here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql?rq=1]

Comment: If there is any chance that field1 isnull you should change the the sum to ifnull(field1,0) + 10 apart from that the update query looks good to me,

Answer (score 1):

"table" is special/reserved word in SQL. Change it to different name ex. "mytable"

```
UPDATE mytable
SET 
  field1 = field1 + 10
WHERE 
  field2 < 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done by using the name table as well, anyways here is the answer using Insert to do it.

```
INSERT INTO table (id, field1, field2) VALUES(1, "value1","value2") ON
DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field1= field1+10 WHERE field2 < 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Which `field1` do you want?  The one from the `SELECT` or the column in the table being updated?

See the documentation about when to use this instead of what you have:

```
... UPDATE field1 = VALUES(field1) + 10
```