# Updating multiple rows from PDO fetch query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I understand to call and update since rows using prepared statements but I'm having trouble understanding how to update multiple records.

I have a simple attendance register with a select box to define if they attended or not. I call the rows in a table format:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Attendance</th>
        </tr>
    <?php if($Event_list->rowCount() > 0) {
    foreach ($Event_list->fetchAll() as $Event_list_row) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo ucwords($Event_list_row['firstname'])." ".ucwords($Event_list_row['surname']); ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $Event_list_row['booking_id']; ?>">
                <select name="outcome">
                    <option value="0">Choose</option>
                    <option value="1">Yes</option>
                    <option value="2">No</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Update" name="update">
</form>
```

I thought I could just use foreach again to update each record, but clearly I'm doing something wrong:

```
if(isset($_POST["update"])) {

    $Update_ID = $_POST["id"];
    $Update_Outcome = $_POST["outcome"];

    foreach($_POST['id'] as $count => $id) {
        $Attendance_Update_SQL = "
        UPDATE event_booking SET
        `confirmed`= :outcome
        WHERE `id`= :id";
        $Attendance_Update = $dbconn->prepare($Attendance_Update_SQL);    
        $Attendance_Update->bindParam(':id', $Update_ID[$count], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $Attendance_Update->bindParam(':outcome', $Update_Outcome[$count], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        if($Attendance_Update->execute()) { 
        // Add in success message?
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:
**Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**
relating to the foreach row

Comment: sidenote: you only need to prepare the statement once. So it would be adviseable to move it outside the loop

Comment: Whilst inefficient for lots of records, I'm not sure I see anything that stands out as being "wrong" with your per item update approach. If you wanted to do a batch update you'll probably need to use an "_INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE._" syntax instead.

Comment: @Scuzzy OP is updating records though, not inserting

Comment: @DarkBee sorry I forgot to close the loop in the example. The update is sitting outside.

Comment: are you calling Attendance_Update->execute() inside the loop?

Comment: @atoms yes, sorry I realise I copied it over incorrectly. I've now updated the question

Comment: @DarkBee It's a neat hack on a table with a primary key to trigger mass record updates, since adding per record logic to an update statement would be overly complex. I have no idea how many records need updating, but this above loop would be inefficient on lots of records. [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql).

Comment: also @JosephGregory can you explain what goes wrong anyway? that's not clear to me. To me it looks like only your last record is being updated, that's what I would expect looking at your code.

Comment: @Scuzzy sorry for not explaining. I want to update all records. A normal attendance list is about 30 records so I want to update them all. I have also added the error I'm getting

Comment: Yep, so the problem is `$_POST['id']` isn't an array, its a string with the last record ID, see my answer and http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays

Comment: Ok arrays are a real week point, so using your method below would solve that?

Comment: Arrays arn't the problem, the problem is your form isn't sending an array, see my quickfix update :)

Comment: @Scuzzy Thx for the reading material

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick Fix:

rename `name="id"` to `name="id[]"`

rename `name="outcome"` to `name="outcome[]"`

Note: *this syntax and reliance on index is problematic when you add checkbox types to a form.*

---

Ok, the biggest problem is your input names are going to conflict

eg `<select name="outcome">` will only set the last records outcome from your form.

I would use `var_dump($_POST)` to understand your post data

Suggestion, rename your "name" attributes as `name="record[id][property]"`...

```
<select name="record[<?php echo $Event_list_row['booking_id']; ?>][outcome]">
  <option value="0">Choose</option>
  <option value="1">Yes</option>
  <option value="2">No</option>
</select>
```

You would then use

```
foreach( $_POST['record'] as $id => $data )
```

where `$id` and `$data['outcome']` is now clearer to understand and use.