# Change multiple rows for one colum

Tags: mysql

I am working in mySQL.  It's a table of members, some are inactive, I want to change the status of inactive ones from active to inactive.   So I know i need to SET `active`=0 WHERE `member`=x  but I have 382 rows to change (multiple values of x)

Hope this makes sense, I am a noob!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Updates in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql)

Comment: You would define a `WHERE` clause which includes all of the target rows.  What logic identifies all of the rows?

Comment: Thanks, the rows I want to change are certain member numbers, e.g. members 2,17,236,4285  (but 382 entries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use in

```
update myTable SET active=0 WHERE member in (, , , , ,);
```

If you have some logic than can select those members then you can add it  to your query.

```
update myTable SET active=0 WHERE member in 
 (select members from myTbale where --- add your logic to get the members---);
```