# What is syntactically wrong with this ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE query?

Tags: mysql, pymysql

**Update:** This issue was resolved in the comments and is awaiting an answer

When executing the following query in PyMySQL, I receive the error ‘`1064, u"You have an error in your SQL syntax;`’ (full error message below)

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` (`id`, `colName1`, `colName2`, `colName3`) 
VALUES (820, 'string', 5, 'N')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `colName1`=VALUES(`colName1`),
    `colName2`=VALUES(`colName2`),
    `colName3`=VALUES(`colName3`)
-- Tried with and without ` surrounding column names after ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

Syntax in Python:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO `table_name` (`id`, `colName1`, `colName2`, `colName3`) VALUES (820, 'string', 5, 'N') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `colName1`=VALUES(`colName1`),`colName2`=VALUES(`colName2`),`colName3`=VALUES(`colName3`)"
```

I received this error both when trying to update many rows (as [suggested elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql), using the format of the accepted answer), and for one row at a time.

As noted in the comments, the stripped down example didn't produce an error (although it was not executed with Python). The following is the actual query. Let me know if other information is needed.

Query string executed in Python:

```
INSERT INTO `Listings` (`id`, `row_last_updated`, `maxBidCountPreRsvMet`, `maxBidPreRsvMet`, `minBidCountPostRsvMet`, `occupancy_status`, `waitingForHnb`, `ownItNow_price`, `high_bid`, `prop_id`, `hot_property`, `status`, `end_date`, `reserve_met`, `hours`, `backupBidSet`, `listing_type`, `low_bid`, `winning_bid`, `bids`, `days`, `high_bid_updated`, `minutes`, `lowBidIsOpt1`) VALUES (820, '2018-01-28 19:16:02', '5', '234000', None, 'N', None, 0, 234000, u'9007092665103', 'N', 'New', '2018-1-31-22-0', 'N', 7, 0, 'AUCN', 0, 0, 5, 3, '2018-01-28 14:16:02.001906', 44, 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `row_last_updated`=VALUES(`row_last_updated`),`maxBidCountPreRsvMet`=VALUES(`maxBidCountPreRsvMet`),`maxBidPreRsvMet`=VALUES(`maxBidPreRsvMet`),`minBidCountPostRsvMet`=VALUES(`minBidCountPostRsvMet`),`occupancy_status`=VALUES(`occupancy_status`),`waitingForHnb`=VALUES(`waitingForHnb`),`ownItNow_price`=VALUES(`ownItNow_price`),`high_bid`=VALUES(`high_bid`),`prop_id`=VALUES(`prop_id`),`hot_property`=VALUES(`hot_property`),`status`=VALUES(`status`),`end_date`=VALUES(`end_date`),`reserve_met`=VALUES(`reserve_met`),`hours`=VALUES(`hours`),`backupBidSet`=VALUES(`backupBidSet`),`listing_type`=VALUES(`listing_type`),`low_bid`=VALUES(`low_bid`),`winning_bid`=VALUES(`winning_bid`),`bids`=VALUES(`bids`),`days`=VALUES(`days`),`high_bid_updated`=VALUES(`high_bid_updated`),`minutes`=VALUES(`minutes`),`lowBidIsOpt1`=VALUES(`lowBidIsOpt1`)
```

The full error message:
`(1064, u"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''9007092665103', 'N', 'New', '2018-1-31-22-0', 'N', 7, 0, 'AUCN', 0, 0, 5, 3, '2' at line 1")`

Side notes: Python `None` values are converted to MySQL `null` values. The same error occurred when changing None values to strings.

Comment: MySql version ?

Comment: The query works fine: http://rextester.com/OTUD99946 - Please post a reproducible example. Also post the full error message.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I believe the version is 5.6.27

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Not sure if helpful, but someone edited out the original Python syntax (where the error was produced), and has been reposted. I'll see what else I can post that's reproducible.

Comment: @Phillip It was me, and I only added line breaks to make it more readable. The original one-liner also works: http://rextester.com/GKJAC56629

Comment: @PaulSpiegel More information may be needed (didn't want to overload the post), but the originally used query string has been added to the post

Comment: No wonder you don't find the error, if you don't use line breaks and don't read the error message. Look for `None` in your VALUES list.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel In PyMySQL Python `None` values are converted to MySQL `null` values. I did read the error message, and added the full error message, if helpful.

Comment: Well.. now you know it's near `'9007092665103'`. So what is `u'9007092665103'` supposed to be?

Comment: The column info for that data is: `name: prop_id,  type: varchar(25) Default:  NULL `

Comment: To be sure, a test changing the None values to strings resulted in the same error

Comment: not sure about `u` prefix https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html

Comment: @Deadooshka Updating the unicode to str fixed the error. Feel free to post as an answer at your convenience, and I will accept it.

Comment: Please post the complete error message. There is a part you have omitted starting 'NEAR ...'.

Comment: The full error message was posted in an edit a few hours ago at "The full error message: " (just double checked the console to verify it was the full message), but I'll make an edit by the initial error message snippet