# Transform two queries into one update query

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to know if it's possible to combine these two query.

My table look like this :

```
------------------------------------
| id | server  | domain   | status |
------------------------------------
| 1  | serv1   | serv1.az | 0      |
| 2  | serv2   | serv2.lo | 0      |
| 3  | serv2   | servNEW  | 1      |
| 4  | serv3   | serv.as  | 0      |
------------------------------------
```

I made these two queries to update the column :

```
UPDATE `table` SET `server` = ? WHERE `server` = ?
UPDATE `table` SET `domain` = ? WHERE `domain` = ?
```

E.g :

```
UPDATE `table` SET `server` = `serv1_NEW` WHERE `server` = `serv1`
UPDATE `table` SET `domain` = `serv1NEW` WHERE `domain` = `serv1.az`
```

**EDIT:**

Corrected syntax error

```
UPDATE `table` SET `server` = `serv1_NEW` WHERE `server` = 'serv1'
UPDATE `table` SET `domain` = `serv1NEW` WHERE `domain` = 'serv1.az'
```

Comment: Multiple fields can be updated by using a comma to divide them.

*UPDATE `table` SET `server` = 'serv1_NEW', `domain` = 'serv1NEW' WHERE `domain` = 'serv1.az';*

Comment: Also, here's a related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql  but I want to point out that dynamic updating multiple rows with different values is usually more trouble than just running two queries back to back, one for each row that needs updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simple case, you can use [CASE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html). For example:

```
UPDATE `table` SET 
`server`= CASE
    WHEN `server` = 'serv1' THEN `serv1_NEW`
    ELSE `server`
END, 
`domain`= CASE
    WHEN `domain` = 'serv1.az' THEN `serv1NEW`
    ELSE `domain`
END
WHERE `server` = 'serv1' OR `domain` = 'serv1.az'
```

But two separate queries are more clear solution for your task

Comment: Alright thank you to point it out. I will stay with these two queries

Comment: @executable still this answer contain syntax errors because of mixing up backticks where single/double quotes should have been used `serv1` and `serv1.az` are string values which should have single/double quotes

Comment: Yes, my mistake while writing the question. I'll correct it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I didn't look it. I fixed the answer.