# how to create mysql update query for updating multiple rows in in one statement for c#.net windows applicaiton

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

**How to write mysql update query for updating multiple rows of `datagridview` in single statement by passing parameters and then executing all together in `c#.net` windows application**

for example create update query like is given below

```
foreach(DatagridViewRow dr in datagridview)
{
   sql = "update table1 set name=@name where id=@id; update table1 set name=@name where id=@id; update table1 set name=@name where id=@id;"
}
```

How to create a **sql** query with **parameters**? So that after creation of query; we can execute it together to make changes in multiple rows.

Comment: Check out this option, which doesn't require datagridview and can be handled in a stored procedure - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65950733/3714181

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to put multiple `Update` queries together.
Here take a look:

```
string sql = "update table1 set name=@name where id=@id";
MySqlParameter pId = new MySqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.BigInt);
MySqlParameter pName = new MySqlParameter("@name", SqlDbType.NVarchar);
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.CommandText = query;
cmd.Parameters.Add(pName);
cmd.Parameters.Add(pId);    
foreach(DatagridViewRow dr in datagridview)
{
    pId.Value = dr.Rows["iDColumn"].ToString();        
    pName.Value = dr.Rows["nameColumn"].ToString();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Additional context on top of this answer - check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql. You can see a SQL query for MySQL, which updates multiple rows with one SQL command. I use this strategy often. I do wish MySQL would support UPSERT syntax...

Comment: thank you for the answer. i am aware of this . I was in search for creating multiple update query (especially for datagridview in c#) and when we excute it all the updates are done together.