# Multiple Updates in MySQL with Foreign Key Constrains

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to construct a single query that will update multiple rows in a table, using the method described here: [Multiple Updates in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql)

Essentially, I'm using the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` method, using a query like

```
INSERT INTO table1 
(id, val1, val2) 
VALUES 
(0, 5, 5)...<etc.> 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
    UPDATE id=VALUES(id), val1=VALUES(val1), val2=VALUES(val2)
```

The problem is that the `id` column is referenced as a foreign key from a different table, so when I try to execute this query, I get a `Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails` error.

Is there a way to make the `INSERT DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` method work with this foreign key constraint (I'd rather not disable the constraint, even temporarily), or am I stuck sending multiple queries to my database?

Comment: Just don't update the foreign key? `INSERT INTO table1 (id, val1, val2) VALUES (0, 5, 5)...<etc.> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE val1=VALUES(val1), val2=VALUES(val2)`

Comment: ON DUPLICATE KEY doesn't fire on a foreign key constraint, so it won't help in this case. Edit your question and show the schemas for the tables involved. So a child table references the ID column? Or visa-versa? Based on the limited info in the question, you may want to add a row for "Not Assigned" the the table causing the constraint to fail. When inserting into this table, use the key for that row.

Comment: Either disable the constraint or fix the data so the constraint is valid.  You can't have it both ways.