# Merge multiple foreach MySQL insert statements into one with PHP array data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I have a PHP array with different items and their respective values, and would need to update each row for each item in a database. Is there a way to only have one query to execute, instead of multiple foreach queries?

```
foreach($array as $key=>$item){
    $image_id = $item['id'];
    $order_id = $item['order_id'];
    $sql = "UPDATE images SET order_id='$order_id' WHERE id='$image_id'";
    $query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
} // end for each
```

Comment: You should parameterize your query instead of injecting values directly. But you would have to execute it multiple times none the less, it'll be better with a prepared statement though.

Comment: This answer [might be useful to you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3466/2310830)

Comment: What's the absolute maximum number of images that will ever get updated at any time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really combine it into one query using `UPDATE`, as the value and condition come in pairs (the value and condition is different for each row you are updating).

There is a hacky fix with `INSERT INTO..ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, but I would refrain from using that - see the [question linked by RiggsFolly in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3466/2310830).

When using a prepared statement, you can execute the same query multiple times (you would have to query it multiple times anyways, even with `mysqli_query()`, but this is optimized and more secure when using a prepared statement).

```
$sql = "UPDATE images SET order_id=? WHERE id=?";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
foreach($array as $key=>$item){
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $item['order_id'], $item['id']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
$stmt->close();
```

If your IDs are integers instead of strings, replace the respective `s` with an `i`.

- [PHP.net on `mysqli::prepare()`](http://php.net/mysqli-prepare)
- [PHP.net on `mysqli-stmt::bind_param()`](http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.bind-param)
- [PHP.net on `mysqli-stmt::execute()`](http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.execute)