# save new divs order avoiding to repeat sql query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

```
<div class="artitle" data-id=1>lorem</div>
<div class="artitle" data-id=2>ipsum</div>
//and so on - about 500 divs
```

using javascript I reordered the divs up and down and need to save this new order in database(column `ind`).

```
let ids = $.map($('.artitle'), (e) => $(e).data('id')).join(',');
let inds = $.map($('.artitle'), (e) => $(e).index()).join(',');
//$.post... - send the variables on remote server
```

**php**

```
$aids = explode(',', $ids);
$ainds = explode(',', $inds);
foreach($aids as $key=>$val){
    $sql = "update arts set ind = :aind where id = :aid";
    $st = $db->prepare($sql);
    $st->execute([
        ":aind" => $ainds[$key],
        ":aid" => $val
    ]);
}
```

It works but is there a better way - to avoid repeating sql query 500 times?

Comment: Well you certainly should not prepare the query inside of the loop.  This causes the DB more work as it has to prepare the query each time.  This (basically) is how SQL Injection is prevented, the instructions (SQL) are sent separate from the Data, this way the DB knows when it's time for Data that there are no instructions in it etc... so by preparing the query again your asking the DB to re-evaluate the same instructions.  That is baring any caching of it, I am not sure about caching, but it's a good practice none-the-less.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix, understand, but can't see how, code pls

Comment: it's not worthy of an answer, but just put these 2 lines above the foreach `$sql = "update arts set ind = :aind where id = :aid";` and `$st = $db->prepare($sql);`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix, thanks a lot, prepare procedures are not now repeated, but execution still **is**.

Comment: As I said the server may cache the prepared statement, I am not sure as to what extent that has but....  Have you actually done any bench marking of the code to see where the time is being spent?   It wouldn't be a bad idea to time it before and after moving that etc...

Comment: Eh? Preparing the query in the loop is EXACTLY what you SHOULD do! Prepare it in the loop, then execute, once, outside the loop.

Comment: @Strawberry, i tried - `prepare inside foreach` and `execute outside` - doesn't work.

Comment: Can you use `INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY ` with the VALUES option

Comment: I am working on an answer, will provide soon with the above `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build a single mysql query using PHP and use the `INSERT INTO` mysql feature([multiple updates in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql) to update multiple rows, below is how you should do it(I haven't used prepared statement, that's for you to figure out since now you have an idea how to build the query pro grammatically) :

**PHP**

```
$aids = explode(',', $ids);
$ainds = explode(',', $inds);

$timeStart = microtime(true);

$sqlQuery = 'INSERT INTO arts (id,ind) ';

foreach($aids as $key=>$val){

    $sqlQuery .= "VALUES ($val,$ainds[$key]),";

}

#REMOVE THE LAST COMA(,)
$sqlQuery = substr($sqlQuery, 0, -1);

$sqlQuery .= 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=VALUES(id),ind=VALUES(ind);';

#RUN THIS AS REQUIRED, YOU GOT YOUR DYNAMICALLY GENERATED MYSQL MULTIPLE UPDATE STATEMENT#
#$sqlQuery;

$timeEnd = microtime(true);
$time = $timeEnd - $timeStart;

echo "Took $time seconds\n";
```

Comment: thanks a lot. How to check the time of execution of a query. Are you sure that `INSERT INTO` and `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is faster than original?

Comment: You could use microtime(true), Updating my answer. But not sure if that will tell the mysql query time too.