# Update Table without loops

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

There is a table `foo` and it has a column called `fooPos`. I ned to update the fooPos column with respect to `id`.

I have the following data

```php
$id = [21,23,34,56,76];
$fooPos = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

How can I update this without using loops?
It's like `21(id) => 1(fooPos), 23 => 2, 34 =>3` etc.,

Comment: What is wrong with loops? Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: It is wrong, we shouldn't be doing any update inside a loop. What if we get 1,00,000 rows to be updated? Is it still okay to update in a loop?

Comment: do you mean put all date in the table without create loops like this : fooPos=myData, and generate table automatically !!  did you mean this .

Comment: It's just example

Comment: You can't. Update queries can only update rows with the same filter and updates at a time. So you will have to write an update query for each of these ids unless there are rows that will get the same `$fooPos`.

Comment: @Jerodev there are many solution to update multiple rows at the same time (with one query). check my answer and https://stackoverflow.com/a/3466/4369919

Answer (score 0):

You have a solution with `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...`, more details in here [Multiple update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3466/4369919)

That solution can trigger an error if the ID doesn't exist and you have some other required fields. In that cas you ca use this solution:

```php
$updateSets = [];
$ids = [21,23,34,56,76];
$fooPos = [1,2,3,4,5];
foreach ($ids as $key => $id) {
    $updateSets[] = 'SELECT '.$id.' as set_id, '.$fooPos[$key].' as pos ';
}

$updateSetsString = implode(' UNION ALL ', $updateSets);

\DB::statement('UPDATE your_table JOIN ('.$updateSetsString.') up_set ON your_table.id = up_set.set_id SET your_table.pos = up_set.pos');
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
function updateTableWithoutQueryLoops()
{
    try {

        $id = collect([21,23,34,56,76]);
        $fooPos = collect([1,2,3,4,5]);
        // To check both parameters should have an equal number of elements.
        if(count($id) == count($fooPos) ) {
            $combinedValues = $id->combine($fooPos);
        } else {
            return 'Please check equal number of elements for give arrays.';
        }

        // Run foreach loop of Combined values
        foreach ($combinedValues as $id => $fooPos) {
            $id = (int) $id;
            $cases[] = "WHEN {$id} then ?";
            $params[] = $fooPos;
            $ids[] = $id;
        }

        $ids = implode(',', $ids);
        $cases = implode(' ', $cases);
        $params[] = \Carbon\Carbon::now();

        return \DB::update("UPDATE `foo` SET `fooPos` = CASE `id` {$cases} END, `updated_at` = ? WHERE `id` in ({$ids})", $params);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return 'Exception message:' . $e->getMessage() . ' with code: ' . $e->getCode();
    }
}
```

```html
function updateTableWithoutQueryLoops()
{
    try {

        $id = collect([21,23,34,56,76]);
        $fooPos = collect([1,2,3,4,5]);
        // To check both parameters should have an equal number of elements.
        if(count($id) == count($fooPos) ) {
            $combinedValues = $id->combine($fooPos);
        } else {
            return 'Please check equal number of elements for give arrays.';
        }

        // Run foreach loop of Combined values
        foreach ($combinedValues as $id => $fooPos) {
            $id = (int) $id;
            $cases[] = "WHEN {$id} then ?";
            $params[] = $fooPos;
            $ids[] = $id;
        }

        $ids = implode(',', $ids);
        $cases = implode(' ', $cases);
        $params[] = \Carbon\Carbon::now();

        return \DB::update("UPDATE `foo` SET `fooPos` = CASE `id` {$cases} END, `updated_at` = ? WHERE `id` in ({$ids})", $params);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return 'Exception message:' . $e->getMessage() . ' with code: ' . $e->getCode();
    }
}
```