# PHP PDO : Multiple UPDATE in a single query

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to get the following to run via a single pdo statement

```
UPDATE `coin_price` SET `coin_id` = 1 WHERE coin_id = 1;
UPDATE `coin_price` SET `coin_id` = 178 WHERE coin_id = 178;
```

and I am getting the following exception

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE `coin_price` SET `coin_id` = 178 WHERE coin_id = 178'` at line 1

I am just running

```
$statement = $this->system[$location]["connection"]->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
```

and getting an exception.  I tried with binding and without.

Is what I am doing not possible?

Note : Both queries run fine via PDO by themselves

Comment: Why are you setting `coin_id` to the same value it already has?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3466/642096

Comment: There is no point running multiple update queries when you can handle it in one. Also setting coin_id to a value it already is assigned doesn't makes sense.

Comment: This is just an example query I'm using for testing

Comment: I don't want to use ON DUPLICATE KEY as I would like to maintain incremental IDs @cetver

Comment: There is no point in maintaining incremental IDs either.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to run multiple statements at once.

Run them separately.  But, if you need transactional semantics, surround by `START TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT`.  (Example:  You don't want a crash between debiting one financial account and crediting another.)

Another plan is to write and `CALL` a Stored Procedure to combine the statements.

If you are concerned about performance, well, you are talking about very few milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can only execute one query at a time. But you can combine them into a single query:

```
UPDATE coin_price
SET coin_id = 
    CASE coin_id
        WHEN 1 THEN 1
        WHEN 178 THEN 178
    END
WHERE coin_id IN (1, 178)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Is it possible to expand this to update as many fields as wanted?

Comment: Yes, you can assign multiple columns, and each of them can contain a `CASE` expression to assign the appropriate value.

Comment: See the duplicate question for examples.